# Scrapy - run spider multiple times

Tags: python, scrapy

I've set up a crawler in this fashion:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def crawler(mood):
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        #crawl music selected by critics on the web
        process.crawl('allmusic_{}_tracks'.format(mood), domain='allmusic.com')
        # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
        process.start() 
        #create containers for scraped data 
        allmusic = []
        allmusic_tracks = []
        allmusic_artists = []
        # #process pipelined files  
        with open('blogs/spiders/allmusic_data/{}_tracks.jl'.format(mood), 'r+') as t: 
            for line in t:
                allmusic.append(json.loads(line))
        #fecth artists and their correspondant tracks
        for item in allmusic:
            allmusic_artists.append(item['artist'])
            allmusic_tracks.append(item['track'])
        return (allmusic_artists, allmusic_tracks)
```

I can run it like so:

```
artist_list, song_list = crawler('bitter')
print artist_list
```

and it works fine.

but if I want to run it several times in a row:

```
artist_list, song_list = crawler('bitter')
artist_list2, song_list2 = crawler('harsh')
```

I get:

`twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`

is there a simple way to set up a wrapper for this spider so I can run it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

it's fairly simple.

an individual process is already defined inside the function.

so, I can just do like this:

```
def crawler(mood1, mood2):
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        #crawl music selected by critics on the web
        process.crawl('allmusic_{}_tracks'.format(mood1), domain='allmusic.com')
        process.crawl('allmusic_{}_tracks'.format(mood2), domain='allmusic.com')
        # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
        process.start()
```

provided that you have classes defined for each process already.